# How to randomly reshuffle letters in words

Tags: r

I am trying to make a word scrambler in R. So i have put some words in a collection and tried to use `strsplit()` to split the letters of each word in the collection.

But I don't understand how to jumble the letters of a word and merge them to one word in R Tool. Does anyone know how can I solve this?

This is what I have done
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvZhc.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please don't upload code or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **stringi** package if you want:

```
> stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(c("hello", "goodbye"))
[1] "oellh"   "deoygob"
```

Answer (score 4):

Once you've split the words, you can use `sample()` to rescramble the letters, and then `paste0()` with `collapse=""`, to concatenate back into a 'word'

```
lapply(words, function(x) paste0(sample(strsplit(x, split="")[[1]]), collapse=""))
```

Comment: Thank you!
I have done it like this :
`scrambled <- lapply(strsplit(words[[word]], ''), \(x) paste(sample(x), collapse=''))`
I had converted the collection to list...quick question....what is this x here?

Comment: There was a comment under @langtang ... i had referred to that comment as well which had a '\'...but now i cannot find the comment

Comment: `\x` is the same as `function(x)` in newer R-Versions. Just a shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner:

```
lapply(lapply(strsplit(strings, ""), sample), paste0, collapse = "")
[[1]]
[1] "elfi"

[[2]]
[1] "vleo"

[[3]]
[1] "rmsyyet"
```

Use `unlist`to get rid of the list:

```
unlist(lapply(lapply(strsplit(strings, ""), sample), paste0, collapse = ""))
```

Data:

```
strings <- c("life", "love", "mystery")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sample` function for this.
here is an example of doing it for a single word. You can use this within your for-loop:

```r
yourword <- "hello"

# split: Split will return a list with one char vector in it.
# We only want to interact with the vector not the list, so we extract the first
# (and only) element with "[[1]]"
jumble <- strsplit(yourword,"")[[1]]
jumble <- sample(jumble, # sample random element from jumble
                 size =  length(jumble), # as many times as the length of jumble
                 # ergo all Letters
                 replace = FALSE # do not sample an element multiple times
                 )
restored <- paste0(jumble,
                   collapse = "" # bas
                   )
```

As the answer from langtang suggests, you can use the `apply` family for this, which is more efficient. But maybe this answer helps the understanding of what R is actually doing here.